# Prove that the diffrence of two functions with equal derivatives on an interval is a constant.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

### If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions with equal derivatives on an interval, what can be said about their difference $f(x)-g(x)$?

I think the answer is their difference is a constant, and prove it using Mean Value Theorem, but I can't write a good proof, Here's my approach:

---

Let function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, assume $a,b, a<b$ are two arbitrary numbers in the given interval, there must exists a point $c\in(a,b)$, such that

$$
\begin{align}
h'(c)&=\frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-a}\\
&=\frac{[f(b)-g(b)]-[f(a)-g(a)]}{b-a}\\
&=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\\
&=f'(c_1)-g'(c_1)\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
since $h'(x)=0$ for all $x$ in the interval, it is a constant on the given interval.
Q.E.D

---

My questions:

1. Is h(x) still a continuous and differentiable function on given interval?
2. Should I differ $c_1$ from $c$?
3. Must $(a,b)$ be an closed interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: you don’t need mvt for this; look at the derivative of $h$ on the interval where $f$ and $g$ have equal derivatives

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$ then so is $h=f-g$. And this with $h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)$. Your proof does not work. If $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c_1)$ and $\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g'(c_2)$ then there is no direct guarantee that $c_1=c_2$.

Comment: The derivative of the difference is the difference of the derivatives, i.e. zero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! could you please help me check my new answer is right or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x), g(x):(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be two differentiable functions with $f'(x)\equiv g'(x)$ on $(a,b)$. I will show that $f(x)-g(x)$ must be constant. Denote $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. $h$ is differentiable as the difference of differentiable functions, and moreover $h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)\equiv 0$ on $(a,b)$. Now let $c,d\in (a,b)$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $a<\xi<b$ s.t $\frac{h(d)-h(c)}{d-c}=h'(\xi)=0$ and therefore $h(c)=h(d)$. This is true for every $c,b\in (a,b)$, and hence $h=f-g$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 1: If a function's derivative is zero on an interval, then it is a constant on that interval
proof:
Let $a,b\quad a<b$ be two arbitrary numbers on the given interval $I$ of a continuous function f(x), according to MVT, there is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=0
$$
it is obviously that $f(b)-f(a)=0\Rightarrow f(b)=f(a)$, so f(x) is a constant on the interval\

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.
$$
\begin{align}
h'(x)&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{h(x+\Delta x)-h(x)}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{[f(x+\Delta x)-g(x+\Delta x)]-[f(x)-g(x)]}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{[f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)]}{\Delta x}-\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{[g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)]}{\Delta x}\\
&=f'(x)-g'(x)\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
according to lemma 1 h'(x) is a constant on the given interval. Q.E.D